# Microsoft Teams Voice Integration and Media Forking / CTI Events

Tags: microsoft-teams

I've invested time today, researching voice integration with Microsoft Teams, with the following requirements.

1. CTI type events when a user answers a call and hangs-up a call. Not much here, the webhook functionality, detailed here under [webhooks and connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/what-are-webhooks-and-connectors), does not seem to apply to voice from what I can gather (it refers to channels) but it does potentially offer the mechanics I am looking for (where I get proactive notification of event changes), "allow users to subscribe to receive notifications and messages from your web services". Any suggestions on how to subscribe to specific Team Users voice events or alternate approaches? Also found the below documentation but still doesn't see to cover the specific call events?

[Use the Microsoft Graph API to get change notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-beta)

2. Is here a way to fork the media of a Teams call to another destination, to say allow further intelligent processing of the on-going conversation for real time analytics?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello @Alan - Regarding your 2nd query, Please let us know whether you want to get the posted media in a Teams call chat or please provide more information ?

Comment: It is a inbound or outbound PSTN call from Teams (one person calling another, one a Teams member the other on the PSTN)

Answer (score 2):

We don't have any event/subscription to specific Team Users voice events.

Please refer below documentation for supported list:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions? view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

You can raise a feedback request here: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472

As an alternative, we have "Azure Communication Services - Voice and video calling events" that you can utilize as per your need.
Reference doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/communication-services-voice-video-events